# How do I create vectors of objects where each object has its own dynamic information

Tags: c++, object, vector

I was wondering how to create a vector of objects and put info from data members into these objects.

For example:

I have a vector

```
 vector<Division> divisions;
```

How do I create instances of the Division object with their own information

This is my constructor :

```
Division(string GUID, string Name, string PhoneNumber, string Description) {

    this->GUID = GUID;
    this->Name = Name;
    this->PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
    this->Description = Description;
}
```

How do I create objects of the class Division and have them each have their own GUID or name for example?

Comment: `divisions.emplace_back(someGUIG, myName, myPhoneNumber, "someone");`?

Comment: Or you ask for GUID/Name generator?

Comment: is this the only constructor? if yes, you actually cannot put an element in the vector without specifying its GUID or name

Comment: @James Please provide [mcve] of *what you really want to do* (and how it doesn't work). Polymorphism and vectors is a different topic than objects without default constructor and vectors.

Comment: Why are you using the constructor body rather than the member initializer list for your constructor - that's inefficient?  This would be better: `Division(string GUID, string Name, string PhoneNumber, string Description) : GUID(GUID), Name(Name), PhoneNumber(PhoneNumber), Description (Description) { }` and you may want to consider naming your members different than your function arguments.